# Pylons + Mako -- Access POST data from templates

Tags: python, templates, pylons, mako

How can I access my request.params post data from my Mako template with Pylons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as in the controller.

```
${request.params['my_param']}
```

or preferably:

```
${request.params.get('my_param', '')}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to import it first, though. from pylons import request